# Groovy Collections: Transform List of Lists in a Map

Tags: collections, groovy

I have the following list of lists:

```
[FOO,1]
[FOO,2]
[BAR,1]
[BAR,2]
[BAR,3]
```

I would like to transform it to a Map like this:

```
FOO:[1,2]
BAR:[1,2,3]
```

I feel like the answer might have to do with using groupBy or inject, but I am not quite "groovy" enough yet to intuitively know the best way to do this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, given:

```
def list = [ ['FOO',1],
             ['FOO',2],
             ['BAR',1],
             ['BAR',2],
             ['BAR',3] ]
```

Yu can group by the first element in each list

```
def map = list.groupBy { it[ 0 ] }
```

This gives you:

```
[ 'FOO': [ ['FOO', 1], ['FOO', 2] ],
  'BAR': [ ['BAR', 1], ['BAR', 2], ['BAR', 3] ] ]
```

So, you need to change each entry in the values list to just be the 2nd element on the list:

```
def result = list.groupBy { it[ 0 ] }
                 .collectEntries { key, value ->
                     [ key, value*.getAt( 1 ) ]
                 }
```

This gives you:

```
[ 'FOO': [ 1, 2 ],
  'BAR': [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

As requested :-)

Answer (score 8):

While tim_yates answer is correct I want to point out an alternative solution:

```
def result = [:].withDefault { [] } // initialize new keys with empty list
list.each {
  result[it[0]] << it[1]
}
```

This approach uses only a single loop and the execution time should be linear to the list size.

Comment: Just made it so simple.